# Scapy script to print all the ips from us to google.com

Tags: python, scapy

I made this script in scapy to print all the ips from my ip to google, every time I send a packet I adding 1 to the ttl until we get to www.google.com
but from some reason its prints me only the first ip over and over. help?

```
from scapy.all import *
def main():
    i=0
    packet= IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP()
    while(packet[IP].src!="www.google.com"):
        packet[IP].ttl= i
        re_packet= sr1(packet)
        print re_packet[IP].src
        i=i+1


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be indexing packet objects with [IP], you want the plain object, the following code works

```
def main():
    i=0
    packet= IP(dst="www.google.com")/ICMP()
    while(packet.src!="www.google.com"):
        packet.ttl= i
        re_packet= sr1(packet)
        print re_packet[IP].src
        i=i+1
```